# Using CombresMvc with TelerikMvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-mvc

I am using the Combres combiner/minifier NuGet package. I am also using the following filters:

```
  <filters>
    <!-- This filter allows relative urls to be used in Css files like in .NET; e.g. "~/MyFolder/MyPic.png"-->
    <filter type="Combres.Filters.FixUrlsInCssFilter, Combres" />
    <!-- This filter allows you to define variables in a CSS file and reuse them throughout the file. -->
    <filter type="Combres.Filters.HandleCssVariablesFilter, Combres" />
    <!-- This filter changes Combres order of ops so that common css variables can be defined in a single
         file and used throughout multiple css files, instead of having to define them in each file. -->   
    <filter type="Combres.Filters.DotLessCssCombineFilter, Combres" />
  </filters>
```

This allows me to define a single CssVariables.css file, and use those variables in any of the other css files (by default, you would have to have variable definitions in each css file, which uses the DotLessCssFilter).

Using the DotLessCssCombineFilter changes the order of operations in Combres so that files are combined FIRST and then variables replaced in the combined file output.

All works extremely well, until I set up the resource set for the telerik stylesheets.

Specifically, it is just the telerik.common.min.css file with an issue. That issue appears on the line:

- html .t-dirty{border-color:#f00 pink pink #f00;filter:chroma(color=pink)}

The offending attribute is the: filter:chroma(color=pink)

Removing that attribute stops a null error from occurring in the combres.axd that stops all processing. That attribute is only used on that line in the entire file (and no where else from what I can tell).

All will work well if you remove that attribute.

Enjoy!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the question. I just wanted to share this so no one else had to go through the telerik css file line by line like I did to isolate the issue!

:)

Enjoy!